# PostgreSQL: how to extract value attribute from XML

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert the following SQL Server query to Postgresql

```
 select CAST(CAST('<IncludeSettle/><StartTime value="2019-03-26 08:45:48.780"></StartTime>' as XML).value('(//StartTime/@value)[1]', 'datetime') AS varchar(40)) + ''')';
```

I have tried converting it to below and got back following error.

```
 select unnest(xpath('//StartTime/@value', xmlparse(document '<IncludeSettle/><StartTime value="2019-03-26 08:45:48.780"></StartTime>')))
```

Error:

```
    ERROR:  invalid XML document
    DETAIL:  line 1: Extra content at the end of the document
    <IncludeSettle/><StartTime value="2010-03-26 08:45:48.780"></StartTim
                               ^
    SQL state: 2200M
```

As a hack, I had made the following change to make it work.

```
 select unnest(xpath('//StartTime/@value', xmlparse(document '<tempzz>'||'<IncludeSettle/><StartTime value="2019-03-26 08:45:48.780"></StartTime>'||'</tempzz>')))
```

Output for Postgresql:

```
 2019-03-26 08:45:48.780
```

I am looking for a better solution. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html), "*The second argument must be a well formed XML document. In particular, it must have a single root node element.*". It *may* be easier to use regex to extract the value you want. Or, do what you're doing, add a root node yourself. I've done exactly that in a few cases in the past where I needed to use xpath but there was no root node.

Comment: Adding the dummy root seems to be the best solution.

Comment: OK, how do I convert this output to timestamp type.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process that by adding the dummy root as you did. The value is already formatted as an ISO timestamp, so you can simply cast it to a timestamp:

But as there is no direct cast from `xml` to `timestamp` you need to cast the result of the `xpath()` to `text` first.

```sql
with data (input) as (
 values ('<IncludeSettle/><StartTime value="2019-03-26 08:45:48.780"></StartTime>')
)
select (xpath('//StartTime/@value', ('<dummy_root>'||input||'</dummy_root>')::xml))[1]::text::timestamp
from data
```